# Swift: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20) in NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I've start a new Swift application with the single line:

`let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()`

and linked binary library CFNetwork.framework

the whole code of my ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {                            
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    }
}
```

And it's works great (as it do mostly nothing) in a simulator. But on a real device it fails with an error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)`

Comment: Did you download iOS 8 beta onto the device?

Comment: Is it necessary? I've set 7.1 in my project setup. As I understand the Swift compiles the same way and all requirements depends on setted version

Comment: I believe there are plans for iOS 7 to support apps with Swift, but I don't know if there's support right now. I wouldn't expect a Swift `Array` or `Dictionary` to work in iOS 7.1 nor any of the new frameworks like `UIAlertController`.

Comment: Surely config goes out of scope immediately?

Comment: The installation of iOS8 has solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that Xcode6 allows to set compliance level for iOS < 8.0 for the Swift, but it compiles anyway for iOS 8. So it can be launched on iOS 7.1 but fails at any shake

Comment: This is also a problem if you use Xcode on Mavericks with one machine but the API you're using depends on Yosemite.